# I try to use module to add my own methods to Array class (but not override it)

Tags: ruby

```
class Check 
  include TestParser
  # so on
end
```

and module structure:

```
module TestParser
  class Array
    def parse_test
      # method
    end
  end
end
```

What I want to achieve is so that every array in file check.rb can be called by `parse_test` method.

Where I got it wrong? (throws undefined method error)

Comment: What do you mean “not override it”? There is no method `parse_test` in Array already, so there’s nothing to be overridden.

Comment: I mean, not override Array class at all.

Comment: Do you want to do `class Array < ::Array`, then use `TestParser::Array` to declare your extended arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a new class `TestParser::Array` containing the `parse_test` method; you have not modified the `Array` class.

You also may be confusing modules and inclusion.

If your goal is to add the method `parse_test` to arrays in your Ruby program, you can put this in a file called `test_parser.rb`, with no module declaration:

```
class Array  
  def parse_test
    # method
  end
end
```

But that will modify the base `Array` class, which you said you didn't want to do. Furthermore, it will make that modification *as soon as the file is* `require`*d*.  No inclusion is necessary.

Outside of a currently-experimental Ruby 2.0 feature called refinements, there's no way to localize those sorts of modifications to base classes (which is called "monkey patching").

If you want arrays to behave differently but only within your code, your best bet is to define your own class that extends Array (that is, make it a container class wrapping and delegating to a regular `Array`, or a subclass if you feel you must).

Answer (score 4):

What you’re looking for is [Ruby 2.0’s refinements](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html). Note that this feature is experimental:

```
module TestParser
  refine Array do
    def parse_test
      42
    end
  end
end

using TestParser  # This applies only to the current file

class Check
  [].parse_test  #=> 42
end
```

You could also inherit from Array and add your method:

```
class TestParser < Array
  def parse_test
    42
  end
end

arr = TestParser.new
arr.is_a? Array  #=> true
arr.parse_test   #=> 42
```

However, I strongly discourage doing either of these things. It would be better to make an object that encapsulates an Array and only provides the methods you need:

```
class TestParser
  def initialize array = []
    @array = array
  end

  def parse_test
    # do stuff to @array
  end
end
```

---

Finally, for why what you have does not work:

```
module TestParser
  class Array
    def parse_test; end
  end
end
```

creates two things: a module `TestParser` with no methods and a class `TestParser::Array` with one method (`parse_test`). Since `TestParser` has no methods, including it into another Module/Class has no effect on the methods available. Including `TestParser` does not do anything with `TestParser::Array`.

Answer (score -1):

> What I want to achieve is so that every array in file check.rb can be
>   called by parse_test method.

You just have to know how to create the array:

```
module TestParser
  class Array
    def parse_test
      puts 'hello'
    end
  end

end

class Check 
  include TestParser

  Array.new.parse_test

  def do_stuff
    Array.new.parse_test
  end
end

Check.new.do_stuff

Check::Array.new.parse_test

--output:--
hello
hello
hello
```

Of course, the TestParser::Array class has none of the methods found in the Array class:

```
module TestParser
  class Array
    def parse_test
      puts 'hello'
    end
  end

end

TestParser::Array.new.parse_test
TestParser::Array.new.size

--output:--
hello
1.rb:11:in `<main>': undefined method `size' for #<TestParser::Array:0x00000101141700> (NoMethodError)
```

That's because you created a new Array class inside the namespace TestParser--you did not reopen ruby's built in Array class.

Then when you write `include TestParser`, that is equivalent to doing this:

```
class AnonymousClass
  class Array
    def parse_test
      puts 'hello'
    end
  end
end

class Check  < AnonymousClass 
  Array.new.parse_test
end
```

And when a constant isn't found in Check, ruby goes up the inheritance chain looking for the constant:

```
class Parent
  CONST = 10
end

class Child < Parent
  puts CONST
end

--output:--
10
```

Because the built in Array class is a constant that lives at the very top of the inheritance chain, the `Array` constant in AnonymousClass hides the ruby built in Array class.  To refer to the ruby built in Array class, you have to write `::Array`:

```
module TestParser
  class Array
    def parse_test
      puts 'hello'
    end
  end

end

class Check 
  include TestParser

  p Array
  p ::Array
end

--output:--
TestParser::Array
Array
```

And for the coup-de-grace*:

```
module TestParser
  class Array
    def parse_test
      puts 'hello'
    end
  end

end


class Check 
  include TestParser
end

puts TestParser::Array.object_id
puts Check::Array.object_id

--output:--
2152779400
2152779400
```

*coup de grace: a death blow to end the suffering of a severely wounded person or animal